# Why use MongoAlchemy when you could subclass a Python Dict?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo, mongoalchemy

A friend recently showed me that you can create an instance that is a subclass of dict in Python, and then use that instance to save, update, etc. Seems like you have more control, and it looks easier as well.

```
class Marker(dict):

  def __init__(self, username, email=None):
      self.username = username
      if email:
         self.email = email
  @property
  def username(self):
      return self.get('username')
  @username.setter
  def username(self, val):
      self['username'] = val
  def save(self):
      db.collection.save(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

Author here. The general reason you'd want to use it (or one of the many similar libraries) is for safety. When you assign a value to a MongoAlchemy Document it does a check a check to make sure all of the constraints you specified are satisfied (e.g. type, lengths of strings, numeric bounds).

It also has a query DSL that can be more pleasant to use than the json-like built in syntax. Here's an example from the docs:

```
>>> query = session.query(BloodDonor)
>>> for donor in query.filter(BloodDonor.first_name == 'Jeff', BloodDonor.age < 30):
>>>    print donor
Jeff Jenkins (male; Age: 28; Type: O+)
```

The MongoAlchemy Session object also allows you to simulate transactions:

```
with session:
    do_stuff()
    session.insert(doc1)
    do_more_stuff()
    session.insert(doc2)
    do_even_more_stuff()
    session.insert(doc3)
    # note that at this point nothing has been inserted
# now things are inserted
```

This doesn't mean that these inserts are one atomic operation—or even that all of the write will succeed—but it does mean that if your application has errors in the "do_stuff" functions that you won't have done half of the inserts.  So it prevents a specific and reasonably common type of error